# In Swift, how can I quickly set my instance variables?

Tags: ios, swift

```
public class User {
    var id: Int
    var fb_id: String?
    var first_name: String?
    var last_name: String?
    var age: Int?
    var distance: Int?
    var login_at_pretty: String?
    var login_at: Int?
    var profile: Profile?
    init(id: Int, fb_id: String?, first_name: String?, last_name: String?, age: Int?, distance: Int?, login_at_pretty: String?, login_at: Int?, profile: Profile?){

        self.id = id
        if let fb_id = fb_id {
            self.fb_id = fb_id
        }
        if let first_name = first_name {
            self.first_name = first_name
        }
        if let last_name = last_name {
            self.last_name = last_name
        }
        if let age = age {
            self.age = age
        }
        if let distance = distance {
            self.distance = distance
        }
        if let login_at_pretty = login_at_pretty {
            self.login_at_pretty = login_at_pretty
        }
        if let login_at = login_at {
            self.login_at = login_at
        }
        if let profile = profile {
            self.profile = profile
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the quickest way to do it? I feel like I'm over typing.

Comment: If your instance variables are optionals, there is no need for `if let`s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your class, you're doing a lot of `if-let` statements that don't provide anything useful.  ie:

```
   if let fb_id = fb_id {
        self.fb_id = fb_id
   }
```

`fb_id` and `self.fb_id` are optionals, so the binding isn't necessary.  Just do:

```
self.fb_id = fb_id
```

On that note however, if you're not planning on subclassing, using a struct would provide a memberwise initializer automagically:

```
public struct User {
    var id: Int
    var fb_id: String?
    var first_name: String?
    var last_name: String?
    var age: Int?
    var distance: Int?
    var login_at_pretty: String?
    var login_at: Int?
    var profile: Profile?
}
```

Check out `Memberwise Initializers for Structure Types` in the [swift docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID213)

Comment: "...provide all of the initialization automagically" - a more accurate way would be to say struct provides memberwise initializer.  You still need to supply the data when instantiating it.